# I've found yaml files describing GeoServer configuration REST API on docs.geoserver.org website. But where are they on my localhost GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver-rest-api, configuration

I've found `yaml` files to generate with *Swagger* the client that will conveniently call the REST API provided by *GeoServer* on *GeoServer* documentation website.

For example at https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/api/#1.0.0/datastores.yaml for datastores management :

[image: Part of the datastores.yaml content]

But I'm expecting to find these `yaml` somewhere also on my *GeoServer* installation on `localhost` (I'm using `Geoserver 2.18`). They should be exposed at an URL.

But which one? I'm wasn't able to find it until now.

---

When you go to the `yaml` documentation, the page that is serving you is using a `swagger-ui` interface from an internal `localhost:8080` *GeoServer*, and you have even the *Swagger* "*Try it out*" buttons.

[image]

It means that *Swagger* knows the structure of the REST services in that `localhost:8080` *Geoserver*.

Aside from this page, which is a perfect and standard one, another one shall exist (that is coming and generated by *Swagger* too) and that returns these descriptions but in `json` format, making it compatible for another *Swagger* tool to generate Client API.

Comment: why do you expect to find them on your local machine? did you download the documentation and put it somewhere?

Comment: @IanTurton It's common that web applications that offer REST services embed the `yaml` or `json` _Swagger/OpenAPI_ that describe them in one of their URLs. The same way that when you have a _SOAP_ URL `http://a.b.c/MySOAPService` you have its description by adding `?WSDL` on it. `http://a.b.c/MySOAPService?WSDL`...

Answer (score 2):

The YAML for GeoServer have been manually created years ago as part of a documentation effort, so they can only be found among the docs:
https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/tree/master/doc/en/api

As part of the documentation, they might not fully reflect the existing code.

Contributions are welcomed to update them, integrate them better with the code, and help keeping them up to date.

Comment: I added more explanations in my post to explain what is missing.

Comment: What's missing is still going to be missing, unless you help "update them, integrate them better with the code, and help keeping them up to date". GeoServer is code is developed based on contracts, not nice ideas :-D

Comment: I am not able to translate [this page](https://www.cnblogs.com/HandyLi/p/11401082.html) but it seems to explain that content is already inside _GeoServer_ web application (and not only in documentation) but not linked to be accessible. About REST services only two ways are used : either a `yaml` (or json description) generates the REST services classes and methods interfaces that are implemented, either existing classes and methods generate the `yaml` file. But a web application offering REST services with aside a `yaml` that would be approaching them? No. I don't think it's done this manner.

Comment: But your idea is a good one. I download the master version of _GeoServer_ to see if I can understand what is happening.